# Getting the elements of list in specific range in Python using negative indexing

Tags: python-3.x

**Input**

```
list1 = ['Apple','Google','MS','Facebook']    
print(list1)    
list1[-4:1]
```

**Output**

> ['Apple', 'Google', 'MS', 'Facebook']
>   ['Apple']

Can anyone please explain the result?

Answer (score 0):

When you use negative indexing, you start at index `-1`. It would seem silly to say `list1[-0]` and have it be different than `list1[0]`. Because of this your code becomes "grab the elements starting from the 4th to last and going to 1". Another way to think of it is `list1[-4]` is the same as `list1[len(list1) - 4]`. So for this you're going in the range `[0, 1)` and only returning the first element.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.

```
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans 
import pandas_datareader as dr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import seaborn as sn

start = '2020-1-1'
end = '2021-1-1'

tickers = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','CSCO','CVX','XOM','GS']
prices_list = []
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        prices = dr.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start)['Adj Close']
        prices = pd.DataFrame(prices)
        prices.columns = [ticker]
        prices_list.append(prices)
    except:
        pass
    prices_df = pd.concat(prices_list,axis=1)
prices_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
prices_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

index -4 means 4th from last element, so `list1[-4:1]` is the same as `list1[0:1]`, which is the same as `[list1[0]]` which is `` [`Apple`] ``

( To give another example, `list1[1:-1]` == `list1[1:3]` == `[list1[1],list1[2]]` == `` [`Google`,`MS`] `` )